# Facebook like count problems

Tags: facebook, curl, facebook-graph-api

I was trying to get a piece of information that is pretty standard and public: the number of likes of a page. However, facebook somehow managed to make this simple task very complicated.

I was trying to use graph API, but for some reason, it's required to have special permission called "Page Public Content Access", which is denied to almost everyone, or have managing permission of the site. In the first place, I don't understand why this is required for getting a piece of information anyone can get, even if not logged in.

Afterward, I was trying to get the like count of a page I created, but it seems that Facebook cannot find it.

It seems that before v5 it was quite easy. But now, it seems like a bug. I researched facebook's community, and some other people were complaining. A guy from facebook said that they'd work on it, but that was 4 months ago. He hasn't replied again.

Does anyone have any idea on how to get the number of like? Perhaps something that I missed?

Comment: You need either Page Public Content Access, or you need to have admin access to the page. That’s simply how it is these days.

Answer (score -1):

```
<?php
    declare(strict_types=1);
    $url='https://www.facebook.com/zuck/videos/10111118208672491/';
    $ch=curl_init();
    curl_setopt_array($ch,array(
        CURLOPT_URL=>$url,
        CURLOPT_ENCODING=>'',
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER=>1,
        CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER=>0,
        //CURLOPT_VERBOSE=>1,
        CURLOPT_USERAGENT=>'bot',

    ));
    $html=curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    // reaction_count:{count:100159}
    $rex='/reaction_count\:\{count\:(?<result>\d+)/';
    preg_match($rex,$html,$result);
    $result=$result['result'];
    var_dump($result);
```